# Disable Cinnamon volume applet's sound when changing volume

Tags: audio, desktop-environment, cinnamon

I recently updated my Linux Mint Debian Edition to update pack 7. Since then, every time I change the volume by scrolling on the volume applet that is on my panel, an annoying beep is played. Similar to the behavior of OSX when changing volume.

I have never understood the point of this, it means I cannot change volume silently and it is extremely annoying. I have checked Cinnamon's sound preferences (and Gnome's, just in case since there is some overlap) and also the pulse audio settings. I have notifications set to off in Cinnamon's sound preferences. I also checked volume applets tab in Cinnamon's settings but the volume applet has no options.

So, how can I remove this annoying beep and get my silent system back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is that Cinnamon's applets are simple javascript files stored under `/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/`. The volume applet script is `/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/sound@cinnamon.org/applet.js`. In that file, there is a subroutine whose job it is to annoy me by making my computer beep at me:

```
_notifyVolumeChange: function() {
    global.cancel_theme_sound(VOLUME_NOTIFY_ID);
    global.play_theme_sound(VOLUME_NOTIFY_ID, 'audio-volume-change');
},
```

Commenting those lines out to make the function do nothing gets rid of the beep:

```
_notifyVolumeChange: function() {
   // global.cancel_theme_sound(VOLUME_NOTIFY_ID);
   // global.play_theme_sound(VOLUME_NOTIFY_ID, 'audio-volume-change');
},
```

That's it, just save the file (you will need to open it as root), restart cinnamon or just remove and then add the applet and the sound is gone.

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to give an updated answer for Cinnamon of LMDE 2 (Debian/jessie).

Since Cinnamon in LMDE 2 there is the option to disable the sound effects when changing the volume: *Sound Settings -> Sounds (Sound Effects) -> Changing the sound volume -> off*

No need to fiddle around with the javascript files.