# Disable "plop" sound in Debian 11 / Gnome when changing the sound volume

Tags: gnome, audio, gnome-shell, gsettings

After update from Debian 10 to 11 and the corresponding update in Gnome, my system is full of unwanted sound effects. Terrible design I want to say to the person responsible for this, if they are by chance reading.

I found [a trick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93368/how-can-i-disable-the-shutter-sound-of-gnome-screenshot) to disable a super loud "analog photo camera shutter" sound when taking screenshots. But there are many other sounds left, especially a "plop" every time I press volume up/down on the keyboard (it was a shitty idea back then when Apple put it into macOS, it is still as bad today), or using the mouse to move the slider in the top-right screen bar volume control.

(Another one is a "drop" sound when no search results are found in Firefox). What's the purpose of setting the "System Sounds" volume in the settings to zero, if apparently system application ignore that setting.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh, it is a glitch/bug in the sound preferences. After [reading this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93365/disable-cinnamon-volume-applets-sound-when-changing-volume?rq=1), I thought this cannot be that it behaves differently, and I pressed mute/unmute a few times and moved the slider for "System Sounds" forth and back. Now the "plop" is gone. I hope for good.

Comment: amazing that an 8 year old glitch is still relevant!